# Is there a solution to enable programatically "show touches" in Android 6 (Marshmallow)?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),"show_touches", 1);
```

This no longer works on Android 6 Marshmallow

Comment: For debugging and testing purposes, you can enable show touches in the developer options...

Comment: I know but what i want is to enable touches programatically in API 23